# Slider control is not working properly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, slider

I want to change textblock value depending on the slider value each time I change it. But it shouldn't be done in XAML, because I want to make manipulations over return data. But the text in the textblock is not changed. Where is the problem?
My XAML is:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" Value="0.2" SmallChange="0.1" Minimum="0" Maximum="10"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,208,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="195" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
```

my WP 8 page code is:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    Slider slider = e.OriginalSource as Slider;
    if (slider != null)
    {
        sliderTBk.Text = slider.Value.ToString();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you check in the debugger if the ValueChanged handler gets called and if it enters the if-clause?

Comment: @FlatEric ValueChanged handler gets called and `value` is null, I don't know why

Comment: Are you sure that `Value` is null? In that case your application would crash and not only not update the `TextBlock`.

Comment: @FlatEric, yes it crashed, but now its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use thi XAML without CodeBehind

```
<TextBlock x:Name="sliderTBk" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider" />
```

This should work.

And dont forget to remove the ValueChanged Eventhandler.

If you have to use CodeBehind:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
  if (slider != null)
  {
    sliderTBk.Text = slider.Value.ToString();
  } 
}
```

Try this becuse i think that

```
 Slider slider = e.OriginalSource as Slider;
```

hides your control x:name="slider"

Comment: I need to make it with CodeBehind

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Why if I have `SmallChange="0.1"` changing the thumb position I'm getting values like 1.23423432 is there a way to make this change step fixed to 0.1?

Comment: Set Large and SmallChange and TickFrequency to 0.1 and set IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"

Comment: I tried, but Error 1 `The member "IsSnapToTickEnabled" is not recognized or is not accessible.` Error 2 `The property 'IsSnapToTickEnabled' does not exist on the type 'Slider' in the XML namespace` Error 3 `The property 'TickFrequency' was not found in type 'Slider'.`

Comment: In my test it works fine ?
    <Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="212,133,0,0" Name="slider1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Interval="1" LargeChange="0.1" TickFrequency="0.1" ValueChanged="slider1_ValueChanged" Value="0.1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" />

Comment: Maybe because I'm using `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit`. I have also this error: `The property 'TickFrequency' does not exist on the type 'Slider' in the XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.`

Comment: ah ... sorry i cant test the wp8 Version right now :( But it has to work ... just take a look at the properties. i am sure you will find it